# Odds of getting y objects in one group when choosing x from a group of N objects without replacement

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So the problem I'm trying to work out is: if you have a group of 30 objects and split it in half, what are the odds that 6 of the objects end up in one group, except I also wanted the general solution.

I think I have it, but I'm not certain and wanted to check here, so here's my thinking:
Call the total number of objects $N$, the number that you're selecting $x$, and the number of objects you're interested in $y$, and then the total number of ways of getting $x$ objects from $N$ is $C(N,x)$.

To get the number of ways in which you have the $y$ objects in that group, I essentially just say that there's a new group of $N-y$ objects (since you've already chosen the other $y$ objects, but this is the bit of thinking that I feel might be wrong) of which you have to choose $x-y$ objects to make up the rest of your selection of $x$. So then if that's all correct, the odds of this situation happening is $\frac{C(N-y,x-y)}{C(N,x)}$, which I wrote out and cancelled a factor of $(N-x)!$ to get $\frac{x!(N-y)!}{N!(x-y)!}$, and this gives a probability of about $8.4\times10^{-3}$ or 1 in 119 for the numbers above, which I guess seems a little bit high but I'm not sure.

Comment: The reasoning is correct. Number of ways to select $x$ objects with $y$ designated objects already in the selection over the number of ways to select $x$ objects overall. This is of course assuming that your selection procedure gives every configuration with equal probability.